# Ruby PHP parsing library?

Tags: ruby, parsing

I need to extract some static data from PHP files in ruby. I've looked around but I couldn't find any practical tools.

Does anyone know of a Ruby lib that would enable me to get the AST from a PHP source file?

Comment: Might it be easier to dump the data from PHP to a format Ruby can more-easily digest?

Comment: Good idea, but in this case he'll need a working PHP version on his server (which is probably a Ruby only server).

Comment: Yeah I have PHP on the server too, but the point is precisely to bypass the PHP : because a) the PHP code in question is *ugly* and buggy and, as much as I'd love to, I cannot refactor it! b) the PHP app needs a complicated installation process that's hard to automate and it doesn't seem worth the trouble to install it, prep the dbs etc. just to dump some fields of the classes

Comment: If it's static data, do you really need a full PHP AST? Isn't there a specific way in which the data is delimited, such that you can simply parse it from the file with a trivial lexer/tokenizer?

Comment: That's what I'll probably end up doing. The data is in the form of nested arrays that are a bit irregular in structure. This is not very hard to parse but not entirely trivial, I figured it would be safer to use a proven tool if it existed :)

Comment: A sample would make a world of difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have php on your server, you could use [PHP-Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) to parse your php files, then output the parsed result (in an easy to read format such as json) for ruby to then read and use.

Although if you can get away with using a regex solution (eg if you just need to grab some constant variable values), it would probably be okay to do that. It is hard to know depending on how complex your input php files are and how much data you need to extract.